# Where is the API document for the usage like `render json: @user`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wonder if there is any explanation of the usage below under http://api.rubyonrails.org/ instead of http://guides.rubyonrails.org.

```
render json: @user
```

Although there is a [page in Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) mentioning this, it does not cover other available options like `:include`, for example:

```
render json: @user, include: { blog: { only: [:name, :permalink]} }
```

I can't believe such common API is hard to find in its official API document.

Comment: Are you by any chance using [ActiveModelSerializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)? I see they have an [include option](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/adapters.md#include-option) while rendering, but I've never seen that used or mentioned before, though that could just be me being out of the loop

Comment: its can be also useful if we want to return `JSON` response for ajax request.
i also use it for debugging purpose of object in controller

Comment: @SimpleLime No, there is no active_model_serializers in my Gemfile.lock.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because it's using as_json method. Refer to:

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json

So, the render method isn't strictly related to as_json options. You should head to the link above.

Answer (score 1):

Dug around a little and found the [ActionController::Renderers documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionController/Renderers.html) which, to `add` a new one states:

> To create a renderer pass it a name and a block. The block takes two arguments, the first is the value paired with its key and the second is the remaining hash of options passed to render.

and then if you [view it's source on GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fd427bb9fe9d0889b8e48a16d67f22d626ab3a4c/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb#L155) you can see when they create the `:json` renderer, they do:

```
add :json do |json, options|
  json = json.to_json(options) unless json.kind_of?(String)
  ...
end
```

So, Rails, is just calling `to_json` on "the value paired with it's key" (which is `@user` in `render json: @user`) passing in all the extras you passed to the `render` call, in this case the `include`.

So if you want to know what the `include` option is doing, you would need to check the [`@user.to_json`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c85d305a67f83f3a92488a641654b85b90b8747a/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb#L33) method, which then calls [`ActiveSupport::JSON.encode`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c85d305a67f83f3a92488a641654b85b90b8747a/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#L19) which just kind of delegates to [`ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::JSONGemEncoder#encode`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c85d305a67f83f3a92488a641654b85b90b8747a/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#L32) which then just calls [`as_json`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) on the object and turns it into a string.